# Stop windows from automatically resizing a specific window when it switches between monitors with different DPIs?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm developing a Windows Qt C++ application, and in it I have a window that I need to have complete control over its position and size. However, if the system has two displays with different DPIs / scaling factors and my window moves between them, Windows will automatically resize this window.

Is there any way I can disable that behavior, but just for this specific window?

Because this is a Qt application, I'd prefer to keep that behavior enabled for the other windows in my app, since Qt manages their behavior as they changes between monitors and I don't want to interfere with that. However, it's fine if I need to use a Windows-specific solution to achieve what I want. (I'm already using `installNativeEventFilter()` in this app.)

In case it matters, I'm using Qt 5.11. I can't upgrade to a newer version at the moment due to project constraints I don't have control over.

Comment: Both Windows and Qt try to be as "helpful" they can there. You have to correct the outcome of their "help" but precisely how is hard to tell from vague prose you posted.

Comment: I agree that more detail will help. But, essentially, you can turn off DPI awareness on a per-thread basis; do that just before you create a window (and turn it back on again after creation) and that window will generally not have any DPI awareness. Well - that works in my stuff for disabling it for HtmlHelp windows. [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are marked as per-monitor [DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process) and handle [`WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-getdpiscaledsize) and [`WM_DPICHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged).

Comment: Can you say more about how to mark the app (or is it the thread?) as per-monitor DPI aware?